# PHP prevent foreach loop from overwriting object

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

This is the fourth time I've tried writing this question, so please bear with me.

I have a PHP object that comes from a DB Query which pulls back the following data:

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [eventId] => 11
        [eventName] => Second Event
        [...]
        [eventChildren] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [childId] => 8
                        [childName] => Jane Doe
                        [...]
                        [gifts] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [giftId] => 73
                                        [giftName] => My two front teeth
                                        [childId] => 8
                                        [userId] => 1
                                        [eventId] => 11
                                    )
                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [giftId] => 74
                                        [giftName] => Wasps
                                        [childId] => 8
                                        [userId] => 1
                                        [eventId] => 11
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
)
```

I'm then running a massive series of `foreach` loops in order to compare the `userId` from the `gifts` array against the `userId` stored in the session cookie.

From these loops I'm creating an array of children and gifts that the user has selected.

The problem is this overwrites my main object rather than creating a new one.

The Loops:

```
$user = $this->session->userdata('user');
$tempEvents = $events;
$userSelection = array();
$flag = FALSE;

foreach ( $tempEvents as $i => $event )
{
    if ( $i == 0 )
    {
        foreach ( $event->eventChildren as $child ) 
        {
            $userGift = array();

            foreach ( $child->gifts as $gift )
            {
                if ( $gift->userId == $user['userId'] )
                {
                    array_push($userGift, $gift);
                    $flag = TRUE;
                }
            }

            $tempChild = $child;
            $tempChild->gifts = $userGift;

            if ( $flag )
            {
                array_push($userSelection, $tempChild);
                $flag = FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I `print_r($events);` it displays the edited list rather than it's full list of events. Is there a way to create a duplicate object and edit that rather than editing the original object?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for clone http://php.net/clone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the "overwriting" is `$tempChild = $child;`.

That will not deep copy the contents of `$child` but make both `$tempChild` and `$child` point towards the same data structure, which obviously isn't desirable in this case.

You should use [`clone`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) as in the below example.

```
$tempChild = clone $child;
```

---

- [**PHP: Object Cloning - Manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

Comment: When I use `clone` I get a server 500 error locally. I'm using the newest version of CodeIgniter and running MAMP Pro with PHP 5.3.5

Comment: @Seth can you check the error_log for details regarding the internal server error? It should be available at `/var/log/apache2/error_log`, or similar.

Comment: [17-Dec-2011 00:23:32] PHP Fatal error:  __clone method called on non-object in /path/to/my/file/site.php on line 24 (`$tempEvents = clone $events;`)

Comment: `$events` is an array and therefore it's impossible to `clone` it, revert that line.. I never recommended you to put a `clone` there, you should be `clone`ing `$child`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$tempEvents = clone $events;
```