# PHP populate array from while loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, while-loop

First of all, I've searched through similar topics and I couldn't find an answer to my issue. So I have an event manager with reoccurring events. I want to store the starting date of every instance of a repeating event up to the ongoing one.

**Goal:**

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    object(DateTime)[288]
      public 'date' => string '2015-08-11 14:30:00' (length=19)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
  1 => 
    object(DateTime)[288]
      public 'date' => string '2015-08-18 14:30:00' (length=19)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
  2 => 
    object(DateTime)[288]
      public 'date' => string '2015-08-25 14:30:00' (length=19)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
  3 => 
    object(DateTime)[288]
      public 'date' => string '2015-09-01 14:30:00' (length=19)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
```

**What I get:**

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    object(DateTime)[288]
      public 'date' => string '2015-09-01 14:30:00' (length=19)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
  1 => 
    object(DateTime)[288]
      public 'date' => string '2015-09-01 14:30:00' (length=19)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
  2 => 
    object(DateTime)[288]
      public 'date' => string '2015-09-01 14:30:00' (length=19)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
  3 => 
    object(DateTime)[288]
      public 'date' => string '2015-09-01 14:30:00' (length=19)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
```

In short, all previous values in the array get overwritten by the last assigned value as the code runs through the loop.

**Code:**

```
class Model_Event {

    private $post_id;

    private $count;

    private $instances;

    public function __construct( $post_id ) {

        $this->post_id = $post_id;
        $this->count = (int) 0;
        $this->instances = array();
        $this->fetch_instances();
    }

    private function fetch_instances() {

        // Abort if no starting date defined.
        if ( !$this->has_date() )
            return;

        // Set the original instance.
        $this->instances[ $this->count ] = $this->datetime( 'both', 'from', false, true );

        // Abort if event not repeating.
        if ( !$this->is_repeating() )
            return;

        while ( !$this->is_stop_reached( $this->instances[ $this->count ], $this->count ) && $this->is_instance_started( $this->instances[ $this->count ] ) ) :

            $this->instances[ $this->count + 1 ] = $this->next_instance( $this->instances[ $this->count ] );

            $this->count++;

        endwhile;

        var_dump($this->instances);

        return;
    }

    private function next_instance( DateTime $dateObject ) {

        if ( $this->repeat_unit() === 'h' )
            return $this->add_hours( $this->repeat_value(), $dateObject );

        if ( $this->repeat_unit() === 'd' )
            return $this->add_days( $this->repeat_value(), $dateObject );

        if ( $this->repeat_unit() === 'w' )
            return $this->add_weeks( $this->repeat_value(), $dateObject );  

        if ( $this->repeat_unit() === 'm' )
            return $this->add_months( $this->repeat_value(), $dateObject );

        if ( $this->repeat_unit() === 'y' )
            return $this->add_years( $this->repeat_value(), $dateObject );
    }

    /**
     * Currently only testing on "repeat every X weeks".
     */
    private function add_weeks( $weeks, DateTime $dateObject ) {

        return $dateObject->modify('+'.$weeks.' week');
    }

...

}
```

I am trying to fix this for over 5 hours and can't seem to wrap my head around the problem. Thank you.

Comment: can you post the difference between `goal` and `What I get:` snippets

Comment: The differences lie in the " public 'date' => string '...' (length=19)" rows. In short, all previous values in the array get overwritten with the latest assigned value.

Comment: may you missed some logic. You are updating entire array while adding new object to it

Comment: @J Santosh The core of the problem is in the fetch_instances() function. The line responsible for getting the next date is: `$this->instances[ $this->count + 1 ] = $this->next_instance( $this->instances[ $this->count ] );`

Comment: But how am I updating the entire array when I specify the key `$this->count + 1`

Comment: i am not good in PHP, but i can say the logic, every time you add a new object to array you have initialize, update and add. i think you are just doing update and add. i experienced this problem in .net. so suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem to be in the following line:

```
$this->instances[ $this->count + 1 ] = $this->next_instance( $this->instances[ $this->count ] );
```

@J Santosh and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8542708/4642600) made me realize that instead of copying the contents of the object assigned, the new instance points to the older one and so on and thus all previous objects get overwritten. So I had to change this line as follows:

```
$this->instances[ $this->count + 1 ] = $this->next_instance( clone $this->instances[ $this->count ] );
```

The [clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) method prevents the objects from being overwritten and therefore I am now getting the desired output.